# How do I package multiple release streams of an application for debian/ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging, apt, dpkg

I'd like to make available multiple release streams of an application (let's call it `scylla` for the purpose of this question).

If a user selects release stream `1.0`, an `apt-get install` will install `scylla-1.0.3`, and an update will install `scylla-1.0.4`.

If a user selects release stream `1.1`, an `apt-get install` will install `scylla-1.1.0`, and an update will install `scylla-1.1.1`.

If a user selects release stream `latest`, an `apt-get install` will install `scylla-1.1.0`, and an update will install `scylla-1.2.1`.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is the one used by gcc package:

- rename the packages to `<package><stream>`, so that you will have `scylla1.0-1.0.x`, `scylla1.1-1.1.x`, `scylla1.0-1.2.x`, ...;
- either make packages from different streams coinstallable (as in gcc case, possibly using alternatives mechanism to provide unversioned names for binaries) or declare conflicts with other streams (that are now represented by packages);
- introduce a package `scylla`, that depends on the latest stream (or, as in the case of gcc, the default stream).

Comment: I'd probably add as another option to create different repositories where the scylla package depends on the different version depending on the repository, so that the user can follow each stream w/o having to worry when the default might change. This is something  done with the mozilla packages for example http://mozilla.debian.net/.